# Play sound from local file storage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to play a sound from the local file storage using react-native-sound.
I have a content url on android to that file.

How do I play the sound?

I already tried adding the sound to my project folders. This way anything works fine. But once I try to play the file from local storage react-native-sound is not able to find that file.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const sound = new Sound(res.uri, Sound.DOCUMENT, (error) =>{
        if(error) {
            console.log("error ", error);
        }
    });
}
play(){
    sound.play((success) => {
        if(!success){
            console.log("didn't play");
        }
    });
}
```

The response from the JavaScript console is:

```
error  {message: "resource not found", code: -1}
didn't play
```

My content url is 100% valid because it already worked with another audio player.

```
console.log(res.uri);

Output: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1F2B-59D9%3AMusic%2FAC_DC%20-%20Thunderstruck.mp3
```

Comment: console.log(res.uri) result?

Comment: console.log output added. I have the mp3 files just on my regular storage. But it should be possible to play them.

Comment: Try to remove a second argument in Sound constructor: `new Sound(res.uri, '', (error) =>...)`. Your URI to file is absolute already, so I don't think you need to specify documents folder explicitly.

Comment: @GeorgiyT. I have already tried that. Sadly doesn't work too.